# Hot do I link MPFR in CMake?

Tags: cmake, linker, mpfr

I'm totally new to cmake, I'm on MacOs and I'm trying to build a c++ library and I need to link my executables to `mpfr` in order to make it work

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(my_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(my_project main.cpp)

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_project GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_project Boost::boost)

find_package(MPFR REQUIRED) # <- It fails here!
target_link_libraries(my_project MPFR::mpfr)
```

When I try to build my project with CLion I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindMPFR.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "MPFR", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "MPFR" with any of
  the following names:

    MPFRConfig.cmake
    mpfr-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "MPFR" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "MPFR_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "MPFR"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

After some research I found out that Cmake was linking correctly both GSL and Boost because there are both a `/usr/local/share/cmake/Modules/FindGSL.cmake` and a `/usr/local/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake` file, So I looked online for a `FindMPFR.cmake` file to insert into the `/usr/local/share/cmake/Modules/` directory, I tried with [this](https://github.com/libigl/eigen/blob/master/cmake/FindMPFR.cmake) one but the error remains the same. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Ok now my CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(my_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(my_project main.cpp )

# Append the cmake/ directory to the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "GSL Found: ${GSL_FOUND}")
target_link_libraries(my_project GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Boost Found: ${Boost_FOUND}")
target_link_libraries(my_project Boost::boost)


find_package(MPFR REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "MPFR Found: ${MPFR_FOUND}")
target_link_libraries(my_project ${MPFR_LIBRARIES})
```

And it works fine :)

Comment: It is script `FindMPFR.cmake` which determines the way, how results of `find_package(MPFR)` should be used. The script which you have downloaded at the top describes 4 variables. Usually, include directories are used in `target_include_directories` call: `target_include_directories(my_project PUBLIC ${MPFR_INCLUDE_DIR})` and libraries are used in `target_link_libraries` call:  `target_link_libraries(my_project PUBLIC ${MPFR_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: As for placement of scripts like `FindXXX.cmake`, all such scripts which are downloaded by you (and are NOT shipped with CMake) should be **shipped with your project**. In `CMakeLists.txt` file of your project you should modify [CMAKE_MODULE_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) variable to contain directory with your script. E.g., if you place the script into `cmake/` subdirectory of your project, you could write `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)`.

Comment: Thank you, but now I have a new problem (I edited the question)

Comment: Ok I solved it, thanks anyway! :)